# Issue with PHP and mysql using SELECT and switch

Tags: php, mysqli, switch-statement

Hi I am trying to Select table based upon directory structure but query is not working properly. Pets is main folder inside which there are folders Dogs , Cats , fishes, Horses
http://animalswecare.com/Pets/Dogs/

http://animalswecare.com/Pets/Cats/

http://animalswecare.com/Pets/Horses/

I am selecting tables based upon dirctory structure like if page is under Pets>Dogs then table dogs_DB , if same code or page is put in Pets>Cats then table cats_DB 
I have used echo for checking and output is at the end of code.

```
 <?php
include('../../connectuser.php');
echo $ab=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$show=explode ("/",$ab);
echo $show[0]."<br />";
echo $show[1]."<br />";
echo $show[2]."<br />";
echo $pagename= $show[1].$show[2];
echo "<br />";
switch ( $pagename ) {

 case 'PetsDogs':  
 $tbl_name = 'dogs_DB';
 break;

 case 'PetsCats':  
 $tbl_name = 'cats_DB';
 break;

 case 'PetsFishes':  
 $tbl_name = 'fishes_DB';
 break;

 case 'PetsHorses':  
 $tbl_name = 'horses_DB';
 break;
 }
 echo $tbl_name;
 echo "<br />";
 echo $sel = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name" or die('error in query');
 $fetch = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sel );

 while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fetch ) ) {

 echo $title;
 $title = $row['title'];
 }
 echo "<br />";

  echo $title."hiii";
 ?>
```

http://animalswecare.com/Pets/Dogs/get_links.php

Output when page is put under Pets>Dogs folder
/Pets/Dogs/get_links.php

Pets

Dogs

PetsDogs

dogs_DB

1

hiii

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the query row with $row['title'] set to empty string. If it's null, the last echo won't output anything. Try var_dump() to get more information about variable.

Comment: $fetch = mysqli_query( $dbc, $sel );
var_dump($fetch);
Output for var_dump is NULL

Comment: if $fetch is null then possible there are two cases:
1) There is no any entry in the database
2) An error has occured during query execution. It can be checked with mysqli_error() function that will return last error.

Answer (score 0):

`$title` seems to be null at the end of the loop  `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fetch ) )`

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't these two lines be the other way around?

```
echo $title;
$title = $row['title'];
```

so:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fetch ) ) {

    $title = $row['title'];
    echo $title;
}
echo "<br />";

echo $title."hiii";
```

Comment: Yes it should be that way, but echo is only for testing and $title is empty , even though it is table.

Comment: what happens if you add var_dump($row); before $title = $row['title'];

Comment: ok before the while loop add if($fetch == null) { echo mysqli_error(); }

Answer (score 0):

Initiate a variable like

```
$pagename = $show[1].$show[2];
```

NOT

```
echo $pagename= $show[1].$show[2];
```

The same for the $title variable inside the while-loop

```
echo $title;
$title = $row['title'];
```

Do instead

```
$title = $row['title'];
echo $title;
```

Since it looks like you want to use the $title variable outside the loop, you will also need to declare it outside.

```
$title = "";
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $fetch ) ) {
 $title = $row['title'];
 echo $title;     
}
echo "<br />";
echo $title."hiii";
```

Comment: No don't want to use outside , out one is just for checking purpose

Comment: echo $pagename= $show[1].$show[2]; and  $pagename= $show[1].$show[2];
doesn't make any difference